# I want to sum six best grades/marks a student scored in different subjects which should include maths and english. Below is my php code

Tags: php, codeigniter, sum

[image: [student score sheet view]()]

The code prints total marks. but i want to print only total marks for the best/highest scores in six subjects.

```
<?php echo get_phrase('total_marks');?> : <?php echo $total_marks;?>
       <br>
       <?php echo get_phrase('average_grade_point');?> : 
            <?php 
                $this->db->where('class_id' , $class_id);
                $this->db->where('year' , $running_year);
                $this->db->from('subject');
                $number_of_subjects = $this->db->count_all_results();
                echo ($total_grade_point / $number_of_subjects);
            ?>
```

Comment: Please provide more details/examples of what you have and what is required.